# Migrate from Simple Press to WP Forum Server

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I currently have Simple press running on my Wordpress installation.

After using Simple Press for a few weeks, I dislike that fact that there are so many feature limitations that can not be overcome without installing plugins. In order to install plugin you have to either write them yourself or pay $30+ to get access to the support forums and plugins library.

Is it possible to migrate my Simple Press data to the [WP Forum Server plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/forum-server/)?